# How to cut and download a part of lengthy youtube video without downloading the whole video to my mac?

Tags: youtube, video-editing

I tried many online tool but some of them not working and Some giving error, maybe due to original video length

Comment: Did you try ffmpeg?

Comment: @Tarik I think in ffmpeg we have to download the whole video first